# Metro Stye App Using File as DataSource No Async

Tags: c#, json, asynchronous, microsoft-metro

Starting on my first Metro App and I'm hating this Async crap.

I have a JSON test file on my C: drive.

I'd  like to read the file as a string without ASync and use it as my DataSource.

I'm having no luck.. It's been 6 hours and I can't even load this data.

Used FileOpenPicker but it uses Async for the PickSingleFileAsync()

Tried IsolatedStorage but they all use Async

Is there anything like Application.DoEvents I can use at the very least.

:(

I need this type of function...

```
public string StringfromFile(string path)
{
    using(FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open))using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
    string data = sr.ReadToEnd();
    return data;   
}
```

Comment: What's the specific problem you're having with doing things asynchronously?

Comment: can you explain a bit more in detail what type of file you are trying to upload as well as where to for example to a file directory, ftp site, database..etc.. more info is better than less

Comment: File is on the C drive. Just want to use it for sample data to test out metrostyle apps. Will be using a DB in the future. I added the old way I'd do it to my post.

Comment: I suggest you check out the new `async` and `await` keywords in C# 5.

Comment: I also hate the async "CRAP".  It does not work in all cases and is horrible for cross platform development in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to use async, but if you want to run synchronously, you can do this

```
Task<StorageFile> task = MyAsyncMethodThatGetsTheFile();
task.Wait();
StorageFile file = task.Result;
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion, but I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry its actually task.Wait() and not task.RunSynchronously(). I've updated my answer.